# How to hide Local Pickup, if the county selected is not the county where the store is?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For an example, if someone selects any county that is not the same county where the store is located, to disable the `Local Pickup` from the checkout.

This is the `cart-shipping.php`:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$formatted_destination    = isset( $formatted_destination ) ? $formatted_destination : WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $package['destination'], ', ' );
$has_calculated_shipping  = ! empty( $has_calculated_shipping );
$show_shipping_calculator = ! empty( $show_shipping_calculator );
$calculator_text          = '';
?>
<tr class="woocommerce-shipping-totals shipping">
    <th><?php echo wp_kses_post( $package_name ); ?></th>
    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $package_name ); ?>">
        <?php if ( $available_methods ) : ?>
            <ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
                <?php foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php
                        if ( 1 < count( $available_methods ) ) {
                            printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" %4$s />', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        } else {
                            printf( '<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" />', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), esc_attr( $method->id ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                        printf( '<label for="shipping_method_%1$s_%2$s">%3$s</label>', $index, esc_attr( sanitize_title( $method->id ) ), wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', $method, $index );
                        ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php if ( is_cart() ) : ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-shipping-destination">
                    <?php
                    if ( $formatted_destination ) {
                        // Translators: $s shipping destination.
                        printf( esc_html__( 'Shipping to %s.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '<strong>' . esc_html( $formatted_destination ) . '</strong>' );
                        $calculator_text = esc_html__( 'Change address', 'woocommerce' );
                    } else {
                        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_estimate_html', __( 'Shipping options will be updated during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php
        elseif ( ! $has_calculated_shipping || ! $formatted_destination ) :
            if ( is_cart() && 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' ) ) {
                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_not_enabled_on_cart_html', __( 'Shipping costs are calculated during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
            } else {
                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_may_be_available_html', __( 'Enter your address to view shipping options.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
            }
        elseif ( ! is_cart() ) :
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html', __( 'There are no shipping options available. Please ensure that your address has been entered correctly, or contact us if you need any help.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
        else :
            // Translators: $s shipping destination.
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html', sprintf( esc_html__( 'No shipping options were found for %s.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '<strong>' . esc_html( $formatted_destination ) . '</strong>' ) ) );
            $calculator_text = esc_html__( 'Enter a different address', 'woocommerce' );
        endif;
        ?>

        <?php if ( $show_package_details ) : ?>
            <?php echo '<p class="woocommerce-shipping-contents"><small>' . esc_html( $package_details ) . '</small></p>'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $show_shipping_calculator ) : ?>
            <?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator( $calculator_text ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I use another module that loads in predefined counties so the customers can't input any county or fake counties. Here is the module's code:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

// Check if WooCommerce is active
if ( ( is_multisite() && array_key_exists( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', get_site_option( 'active_sitewide_plugins', array() ) ) ) ||
    in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    class WC_City_Select {

        // plugin version
        const VERSION = '1.0.1';

        private $plugin_path;
        private $plugin_url;

        private $cities;
        private $dropdown_cities;

        public function __construct() {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', array( $this, 'billing_fields' ), 10, 2 );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', array( $this, 'shipping_fields' ), 10, 2 );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_city', array( $this, 'form_field_city' ), 10, 4 );

            //js scripts
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'load_scripts' ) );
        }

        public function billing_fields( $fields, $country ) {
            $fields['billing_city']['type'] = 'city';

            return $fields;
        }

        public function shipping_fields( $fields, $country ) {
            $fields['shipping_city']['type'] = 'city';

            return $fields;
        }

        public function get_cities( $cc = null ) {
            if ( empty( $this->cities ) ) {
                $this->load_country_cities();
            }

            if ( ! is_null( $cc ) ) {
                return isset( $this->cities[ $cc ] ) ? $this->cities[ $cc ] : false;
            } else {
                return $this->cities;
            }
        }

        public function load_country_cities() {
            global $cities;

            // Load only the city files the shop owner wants/needs.
            $allowed = array_merge( WC()->countries->get_allowed_countries(), WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() );

            if ( $allowed ) {
                foreach ( $allowed as $code => $country ) {
                    if ( ! isset( $cities[ $code ] ) && file_exists( $this->get_plugin_path() . '/cities/' . $code . '.php' ) ) {
                        include( $this->get_plugin_path() . '/cities/' . $code . '.php' );
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->cities = apply_filters( 'wc_city_select_cities', $cities );
        }

        private function add_to_dropdown($item) {
            $this->dropdown_cities[] = $item;
        }

        public function form_field_city( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {

            // Do we need a clear div?
            if ( ( ! empty( $args['clear'] ) ) ) {
                $after = '<div class="clear"></div>';
            } else {
                $after = '';
            }

            // Required markup
            if ( $args['required'] ) {
                $args['class'][] = 'validate-required';
                $required = ' <abbr class="required" title="' . esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce'  ) . '">*</abbr>';
            } else {
                $required = '';
            }

            // Custom attribute handling
            $custom_attributes = array();

            if ( ! empty( $args['custom_attributes'] ) && is_array( $args['custom_attributes'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $args['custom_attributes'] as $attribute => $attribute_value ) {
                    $custom_attributes[] = esc_attr( $attribute ) . '="' . esc_attr( $attribute_value ) . '"';
                }
            }

            // Validate classes
            if ( ! empty( $args['validate'] ) ) {
                foreach( $args['validate'] as $validate ) {
                    $args['class'][] = 'validate-' . $validate;
                }
            }

            // field p and label
            $field  = '<p class="form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '_field">';
            if ( $args['label'] ) {
                $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) ) .'">' . $args['label']. $required . '</label>';
            }

            // Get Country
            $country_key = $key == 'billing_city' ? 'billing_country' : 'shipping_country';
            $current_cc  = WC()->checkout->get_value( $country_key );

            $state_key = $key == 'billing_city' ? 'billing_state' : 'shipping_state';
            $current_sc  = WC()->checkout->get_value( $state_key );

            // Get country cities
            $cities = $this->get_cities( $current_cc );

            if ( is_array( $cities ) ) {

                $field .= '<select name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '" class="city_select ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) ) .'" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '">
                    <option value="">'. __( 'Select an option&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';

                if ( $current_sc && $cities[ $current_sc ] ) {
                    $this->dropdown_cities = $cities[ $current_sc ];
                } else {
                    $this->dropdown_cities = [];
                    array_walk_recursive( $cities, array( $this, 'add_to_dropdown' ) );
                    sort( $this->dropdown_cities );
                }

                foreach ( $this->dropdown_cities as $city_name ) {
                    $field .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $city_name ) . '" '.selected( $value, $city_name, false ) . '>' . $city_name .'</option>';
                }

                $field .= '</select>';

            } else {

                $field .= '<input type="text" class="input-text ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) ) .'" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"  placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' />';
            }

            // field description and close wrapper
            if ( $args['description'] ) {
                $field .= '<span class="description">' . esc_attr( $args['description'] ) . '</span>';
            }

            $field .= '</p>' . $after;

            return $field;
        }

        public function load_scripts() {
            if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) {

                $city_select_path = $this->get_plugin_url() . 'assets/js/city-select.js';
                wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-city-select', $city_select_path, array( 'jquery', 'woocommerce' ), self::VERSION, true );

                $cities = json_encode( $this->get_cities() );
                wp_localize_script( 'wc-city-select', 'wc_city_select_params', array(
                    'cities' => $cities,
                    'i18n_select_city_text' => esc_attr__( 'Select an option&hellip;', 'woocommerce' )
                ) );
            }
        }

        public function get_plugin_path() {

            if ( $this->plugin_path ) {
                return $this->plugin_path;
            }

            return $this->plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        }

        public function get_plugin_url() {

            if ( $this->plugin_url ) {
                return $this->plugin_url;
            }

            return $this->plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
        }
    }

    $GLOBALS['wc_city_select'] = new WC_City_Select();
}
```

and the cities and counties:

```
<?php
/**
 * Romanian cities
 */
global $cities;

$cities['RO'] = array(
    'AB' => array(
        'ALBA IULIA',
        'Sebes',
    ) ,
    'AG' => array(
        'PITESTI',
        'CURTEA DE ARGES',
    ) ,
    'CJ' => array(
        'CLUJ-NAPOCA',
        'Apahida',
        'FLORESTI',
    ) ,
);
```

I want to disable `Local pickup` if the select county isn't the cities from CJ (the last county).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated*

Try the following (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'local_pickup_for_defined_cities', 10, 2 );
function local_pickup_for_defined_cities( $rates, $package ) {
    if( $package['destination']['country'] === 'RO' 
    && isset($package['destination']['state']) 
    && $package['destination']['state'] !== 'CJ' ) {
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if ( $rate->method_id === 'local_pickup' ) {
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I tried it, but no matter what I choose in shipping location, the `Local Pickup` will still be there.

Mention that the code you provided I added it in functions.php in theme.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that `cart-shipping.php` is not in the child theme.

Comment: I have updated my code with something a bit different based on the shipping package destination country and state instead of the `WC()->customer` data. It should also work the same way, than your answer code.

Answer (score 0):

Modified a bit your current code.

```
function hide_local_pickup_based_on_county( $rates, $package ) {
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    $shipping_state = WC()->customer->get_shipping_state();

    // Check if the shipping country is Romania and the state is 'CJ' (Cluj-Napoca region)
    if ( $shipping_country === 'RO' && $shipping_state !== 'CJ' ) {
        // Loop through the rates and remove "local_pickup" if present
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if ( $rate->method_id === 'local_pickup' ) {
                unset( $rates[ $rate_key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_local_pickup_based_on_county', 10, 2 );
```